# Java - Component Clicked In JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlist, mouselistener

I have a `JList<JPanel>` that includes a `JCheckBox` and `JLabel`. I need to find out which one was clicked. I am using a `MouseAdapter`. I can get the `JPanel` with

```
int index = locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
getModel().getElementAt(index);
```

But I can't find a way to determine what `Component` in the `JPanel` was clicked.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I will refrain from writing an actual answer because I don't really know swing, but here's a suggestion: shouldn't all those components be able to have their own mouse listeners? Doesn't that generally solve the issue?

Comment: @Irfy: JLists don't hold actual components but instead uses a renderer that *render* images that *look like* components. That's what makes this problem a bit trickier than it seems.

Comment: Alright, I'm giving up here. :-)

Comment: I'm curious now. Could the OP post a code sample to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: How about using [mouseevent#getSource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource()) method to find the clicked object in your eventListener?

Comment: @KorhanÖztürk it returns the `JList<JPanel>`.

Comment: @Irfy what do you want to see? I have a `JList<JPanel>` with a `MouseAdapter` where I am trying to solve this problem. You should be able to figure out what I have from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`JList.addListSelectionListener(ListSelectionListener)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#addListSelectionListener%28javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener%29).

The [`ListSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html) provides a [`ListSelectionEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionEvent.html).  See the [methods of the event](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionEvent.html#method_summary) to get access to the 1st and last indices of the user's selection.  See also [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) in the tutorials for further tips & working source.

Comment: +1 for the correct approach. Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your attempt to implement the listener.

Comment: I agree with trashgod.  If you want further help, post an SSCCE of your best attempt using the `ListSelectionListener`.